# What does it mean for a set to be a member of $\aleph$?

Tags: computability

I've seen the following two definitions in my slides:

1. $S \subseteq \aleph$ is semi-decidable iff there exists a partially computable function g where
   $S = \{x \in \aleph\ |\ g(x)\downarrow \}$
2. $S \subseteq \aleph$ is re iff $S = \phi$ or there exists a totally computable function $f$ where
   $S = \{y\ |\ \exists x f(x) == y\}$

I know that $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$ represent set cardinalities but what does it mean if there is no subscript and it is used in the above context?

Comment: Surely it's a meant to denote the set of natural numbers. This is not standard notation - maybe it's just a typo for $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: If $\aleph$ is to be used by itself, it should be defined first.  (Or maybe it is a misprint for $\mathbb N$ ?)

Comment: I continue to see it in my class slides though, and I haven't seen a definition. It could be a placeholder for a set of sets of some kind, but I guess then you'd just use the universal set.